# How do you sustain product development if every customer is allowed to change the code?

Tags: project-management, specifications, branch

How do you cope with that?

Is it normal to allow the costumer to change the software as often as he wants? I´m working in a environment where there are no specs and constant requests for changes.

For every new costumer we have to create a new branch and makes so many changes that by the time I  finish I have a complete different product. I´m pretty much losing my interest in programing because of that.

So, am I wrong to say that the costumer should not be allowed to change the software at his will?

English is my second language, so please excuse any mistake.

> **Related:**
>   [How to deal with poorly informed customer choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627/how-to-deal-with-poorly-informed-customer-choices)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627/how-to-deal-with-poorly-informed-customer-choices (sorry)

Comment: Thanks, the question is related, but I´m really trying to find out if the situation I´m in is usual.

Comment: No, it's not unusual. This happens all the time. You (or your management) need to learn how to deal with it, if managed properly it won't get you down so much.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate.  The previous case was talking about custom software development.  This question seems to be more about how do you make choices for a product of general interest when customers request changes to it for their environment.  Different situation, different question.

Comment: That's what I´m looking for, any advice on a book or any other resources where I can read about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I originally missed the part that you have many customers and are customizing a single piece of software for each.  I'll leave my original answer for reference, but it's not really applicable to this particular situation.

In your case, I would suggest that you need a different tack to addressing customer concerns.  One technique I have seen used is that any changes need to be consistent with making the product more useful for all customers.  This would mean that you can say yes to many changes.  For example, making the UI customizable via templates.  That would benefit all customers, but may be driven by a particular customer's desire to fit the look-and-feel into their standard.  But it would also mean that you need to say no to some requests, or modify them in a way that they are generalized to be useful to all.

You may also want to have your customers use something like [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com) to make feature (and bug) requests and vote on them.  This allows your customers to have some direct input into the direction of the product, but forces the requests to be filtered through all of them.  Again, you need not always accept the highest rated requests and you can accept some lower rated requests.  The guiding principle ought to be making your product useful to the widest range of customers.

I don't think that it's practical to have a separate, custom branch for each customer unless you plan to have only a limited number of very high-paying customers.  Eventually, your version control system will become your bottleneck and not allow your company to grow or even serve your current customers well.

Once you get into a more sustainable feature selection mode, my original answer may still apply.  Hope this helps.

**Original**

I'll say up front that some customers are just not worth having.  Only you can tell when this is the case.

Typically, though, it's our job to discover what the customer actually needs and deliver that.  I'd recommend following an agile development methodology to do this.  Rarely does a customer actually know up front exactly what he needs.  Even more rarely does a developer understand what a customer needs before they start writing code.  Agile methods embrace this reality and follow practices that make change less damaging to the process.

First, agile methods employ lightweight processes and delays making decisions until the latest possible moment.  There is "just enough" up front planning to lay out a basic architectural framework, but for the most part it is design-as-you-go.  This is not as freewheeling as it sounds as the techniques used in agile methods, such as TDD, pair programming, refactoring, etc. are sound techniques that encourage good design and design improvement.

Second, agile methods are light on documentation.  While not documentation-free, these methods keep document maintenance to a minimum.  One of the worst aspects of change is that documentation becomes dated and must be constantly updated to be correct. Agile methods identifies those documents that are truly useful and maintains those, but other documents that become out of date can be discarded.  They are used in the moment as needed, but you are not tied to them.  Agile methods put a premium on the code, and tests, being self-documenting.

Third, agile methods encourage a cooperative form of development based on mutual trust.  This goes both ways.  The customer must trust that you have their best interests in mind, while you must trust that the customer knows or, at least, can recognize what he needs when he sees it.

Lastly, the hallmark of agility is **release early, release often**.  Getting the product in the customer's hands early is the best way to get feedback (again, early) on what he really needs.  Once you have a concrete product you'll start getting information on the changes that really matter.  By planning to release early and often, and coupling it with other agile practices, you'll also build a framework into which change can fit more easily.

Even when following these methods, though, as I said earlier: some customers are not worth having.  If your customer doesn't trust you enough to follow your advice when a change is bad or if the customer doesn't know and can't recognize what he truly wants, then there may come a time to sever your ties with them.  I'd suggest that talking with them and letting them know that you want to get them what they need, but they need to know what that is.  Spend some time talking about it so that you both have a better understanding of the goal and put into place agile methods to deal with the reality of change.  If they are still unreasonable, then perhaps it's not going to be a good fit for you.

Answer (score 2):

> am I wrong to say that the costumer
>   should not be allowed to change the
>   software at his will?

Who owns the software? You or them?

If I own a house, I can hire someone to paint it in a different color every week if I want to. If the painter complains, I can get a new painter. If I run out of money, maybe it is because I am an idiot. But the painter did nothing wrong in painting my house, getting my money and using it to feed his family.

If I own a certain software, I *am* allowed to do whatever I want with it. And if you don't do it, then I'll ask someone else.

Comment: But you don't interfere in what kind of technique the painter is using while painting those walls. Also, the wall has to be there in order to be painted. And why even build a wall if it should't be there in the first place? Customers don't always make the right decisions just because they are customers. And that's where the programmer comes in, to aid and help the customer make the right decisions.

Comment: The wall is there, it's the wall of my house. In my example, it is clearly stupid to paint the wall every week - but it's not the painter's fault to do it, it's mine. It's obvious that I should spend my money in useful things. However, _I_ am the one in charge of assessing this.

Comment: I see your point Daniel, but would the painter be able to do proper job if ask him to change the color before he even finish with the first one?

Comment: Charge them for the extra work. It's easy.

Answer (score 1):

specing out the app is as important (more even) then implementation.  Giving the customer at least a base line document, UI mock up or something like that i think is critical.

you have to accept change requests as the system evolves and matures, otherwise the system will suffer from entropy and any hard work you have put in will be lost forever.  if it is a more commercial product try and restrict to changes that all your customers want. then everyone is getting added value.

If you have baseline documentation you can then charge for customization.  the less you want to do the customization the more you charge :P make sure you document and estimate all the change requests. (i use fogbugz for this but there are many other tools out there) If the customer is paying for the changes then at tleat you will be getting renumerated for the pain of changing the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your company is running itself hopelessly into the ground.

You should go job-hunting immediately.

Comment: This is only true if they don't charge the customer for the changes they make; which is not a very wise strategy.

Answer (score 0):

before i put forward my suggestion, i should say i personally believe that a business is there to make money. so if a client is willing to pay for something they want, figure out how to accommodate them (rather then turn them away).

now, ***a*** solution:

i was at a company where they had a software package which they sold to many government organisations - each with their own particular tweaks and features.

i asked the managing director how they avoid version hell - considering they have to maintain a specific version for each client. he said "we dont, everyone gets the same version". they simply maintain one version for all clients, but switch off features which arent specific to a client.

- LM